# Creating a speech bubble with dynamic height using CSS

Tags: css

I need to get a speech bubble that looks something like this via CSS:

[image]

I do not need to set default height for a box. It must have dynamic height. And if the height is increased, the left arrow must be in the center.

I looked through some examples, but I don't know how to change the height! Here is the code I have:

```
<style>
    .bubble
    {
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: 120px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: gray;
    margin-left:50px;
    }

    .bubble:after
    {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px;
    left: -15px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 15px 15px 15px 0;
    border-color: transparent gray;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    }
</style>
<div class="bubble"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ugazoh/4/edit)

Make

```
 top: 40%;
 bottom: 50%;
```

in your **.bubble:after** in CSS script

You have to check it by changing the .**bubble** height